# Add value to a string only if value is not equal to 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how can I add a value to a string only when the value is not 0?

e.g. value={"https://google.com?search=" + query + "&lang=" + language}

I want to add &lang= only if lang is not 0.

When language == 0, expected answer:
https://google.com?search=exampleQuery

When language is something else e.g. language == "en":
https://google.com?search=exampleQuery&lang=en

I tried using tenery operator and optional chaining but only allow to optional chain function, not string.

Comment: why the curvy brackets? is that an object?

Comment: Are you wanting to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)?

Comment: @ChrisG curly braces are for [passing an expression to a prop in JSX](https://react.dev/learn/passing-props-to-a-component)

Comment: yes I know but he is using `+` to concatenate his variables to the string

Comment: FWIW: The canonical form for a Google query URL uses `/search` for the path and should set the query text to the `q` parameter — e.g. `https://www.google.com/search?q=exampleQuery`

Answer (score 2):

You could check the value and return oly if necessary.

```js
const
    addNotZero = (key, value) => value ? `&${key}=${value}` : '';
    

console.log(`https://google.com?search=x${addNotZero('lang', 0)}`);
console.log(`https://google.com?search=x${addNotZero('lang', 1)}`);
```

Comment: [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams) might helpful?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, right, but it's just the same with the check.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76220063/add-value-to-a-string-only-if-value-is-not-equal-to-0#comment134412600_76220158) @NinaScholz Not if `0` is a string — this answer assumes it's a number, but that's not clear in the question details.

Comment: if it is a string you get `"https://google.com?search=x&amp;lang=en"` is there a reason for that extra `&amp;`? I got same result on my end with another method

Answer (score 1):

The answer you're looking for is:

`value = { "https://google.com?search=" + query + (lang !== 0 ? "&lang="+language : null ) }`

You can add an if inline to cheek if `lang` is not 0.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`value={("https://google.com?search=" + query + "&lang=" + language).replace('&lang=0', '')}`
let's try this: "replace" is searching `&lang=0` if succesfull just replacing with empty string
*with just variable, I mean without curve brackets is working in my node

Answer (score -1):

```
function x(path, langCode, number){
 if(number){
  return  path+='&lang='+langCode;
 }

 return path;
}

 console.log(x('https://google.com?search=exampleQuery', 'en', 0));
console.log(x('https://google.com?search=exampleQuery', 'en', 1));
```